# what is _somenumber in the ajax call query string in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax jquery for most of my ajax calls , it always appends the following string

`&_=1292194867553` at the end of the url , may i know what is this no

is it something related to `ajax cache false or true` , i tried changing both to true and both to false , but it still adds this number at the end of the call

Thanks `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's designed to prevent the AJAX response from being cached by the browser by altering the requested URI. The random number is most probably a timestamp so it is never the same for subsequent requests.

In response to the second part of your question, set the `cache` property to `true` to prevent this. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: it should be added only when we set the cache to false right??

Comment: @gov That's what the API says. By default, `cache` is set to `true` for all requests except for `jsonp` and `script` types.

Answer (score 1):

This parameter is used to prevent caching. The number is changed every time (it is a millisecond timestamp, if i recall  correctly). This prevents the browser from caching that URL since it is considered a different query.

Comment: what happens if the browser caches the url , it get the same results all the time ??? you mean if it is same url , the browser won't request the database again??

Comment: @gov: It depends on the response headers, but if the query changes, it is ensured that it gets loaded, since the browser did not request this URL before. The content of a request has nothing to do with caching (at least not directly).